# How to find stepped frequency continuous wave gpr range?

Tags: radar

As far as I know, the range of a sfcw (stepped frequency continuous wave) GPR is affected by bandwidth and number of frequency steps. However, when playing with Matlab's Radar Waveform Analyzer, I noticed that range changes proportional to PRI and pulse width (both are the same value since continuous wave). Is that normal?

In the images, you can see that changing that value only affects range drastically.

[image: pri 0.0001]

[image: pri 0.0003]

Comment: I'm guessing you mean Stepped Frequency Carrier Wave Ground Penetrating Radar, but it might be nice to translate the TLAs (and ETLA) in the question. Edit ; except that's a helluva range for Ground Penetrating Radar so it can't be.

Comment: If this is for detection of landmines you need 1-5GHz range for 5cm resolution and superheterodyne IF just below 1GHz

Comment: eg 800 MHz IF with PLL synth and then choose steps and PW depending on desired SNR for low error detection

Comment: @BrianDrummond I'm new about electonics, what translation should I do. Matlab's waveform analyzer is not specific to GPR.

Comment: Well you translated SFCW now but not GPR. For conventional radar isn't it obvious that (theoretical max) range increases as repetition rate reduces? As Tony says you probably need some very different parameter values if you really do mean ground penetrating radar.

Comment: I only read about GPR. I thought GPR would be very familiar to conventional radars. I guess I'll have to read about general radars.